# Voice to String using RecognizerIntent not working

Tags: android, textview, voice-recognition, microphone

I'm trying to include a microphone button where user can click it and it can prompt a voice input from the user. Then the voice input will be converted into String and shown in a TextView in my android app. For now, the voice input can be prompted but the converted String will not be shown in my TextView and there are no crashes or logcat. Just that it wont be shown in my TextView. All this is happening in a class which extends Fragment.

Below is the code for my microphone button :-

```
//Button to activate voice recognition
        microphonebutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_microphone);

        microphonebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)  {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support speech input !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

The method onActivityResult:-

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (resultCode) {
            case 10:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    texttotranslate.setText("");
                    texttotranslate.setText(result.get(0), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

I got these codes from a tutorial on youtube and it seemed to be working fine for the person who was presenting the tutorial.

Comment: Follow tutorial at [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) and make sure you have microphone permissions for the app

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the method onActivityResult. In the switch you are chechking the resultCode twice. First you should check the requestCode. The requestCode is the code which you defined in startActivityForResult, in your case 10.